# How to properly define and use parameters in C macro functions?

Tags: c, function, parameters, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to use a basic macro in C to access a certain Bit b in a char-Array (*char) Arr:

```
#define TstBit (Arr,b) ( Arr[b/8] & (1 << (b%8)) )
```

however upon usage like such:

```
int foo(const char *charArray) {  
  int readindex = 0;  
  [...]  
    if(TstBit(charArray,readIndex++)) {
```

I get an error on the line with the #define-Statement:

```
main.c | line 7 | error: 'Arr' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I'm suspecting I'm either passing the arguments poorly when calling the Function or that the #define needs some more parentheses.

Comment: Another problem with this macro, after you've fixed the spaces, is that `TstBit(charArray, readIndex++)` will increment `readIndex` twice, and moreover it has undefined behavior because there is no [sequence point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior) in between the two.  This is one of many reasons why you should strongly consider using a function instead (perhaps with `inline`).

Comment: @NateEldredge definetly will do. Not worth the hassle at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space after `TstBit` seems to be the problem here. The pre-processor, unlike the C compiler, is a bit more fussy about spaces.

With your macro, what the pre-processor does is replace all occurrences of `TstBit` with `(Arr,b)` which is not your intention.

```
#define TstBit(Arr,b) ( Arr[b/8] & (1 << (b%8)) )
```

should work the way you want.

**EDIT:** Also note that there is a problem with the way you are trying to use this macro, as noted in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62436396/how-to-properly-define-and-use-parameters-in-c-macro-functions#comment110423045_62436396)!

Macro arguments should ideally not have side-effects. If they do, you should take care that they do not lead to undefined or unintended behaviour.

Comment: As simple as that, indeed. Thanks!

Comment: It isn't really quite as simple as that, please see Nate's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62436396/how-to-properly-define-and-use-parameters-in-c-macro-functions#comment110423045_62436396) that the macro causes *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks! I'll link that comment in my answer as well.